# How to fix RoutingError for a GET request looking for a file /sw/js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am going to a URL endpoint that is rendering a JSON response, yet I see this error in my rails server logs:

> Started GET "/sw.js" for ::1 at 2019-07-08 22:39:43 +0530
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sw.js"):
>
> actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in 'call' 
>   web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in 'call_app'
>   web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in 'block in call'
>   web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in 'catch'
>   web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in 'call'
>   actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in 'call'
>   railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in 'call_app'
>   railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in 'block in call'
>   activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in 'block in tagged'
>   activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in 'tagged'
>   activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in 'tagged'
>   railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in 'call'
>   sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in 'call'
>   actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in 'call'
>   actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in 'call'
>   rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in 'call'
>   rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in 'call'
>   activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in 'call'
>   actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in 'call'
>   actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in 'call'
>   rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in 'call'
>   railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in 'call'
>   puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in 'call'
>   puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in 'handle_request'
>   puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in 'process_client'
>   puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in 'block in run'
>   puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in 'block in spawn_thread'
>   Started GET "/search_stocks?utf8=%E2%9C%93&stock=GOOG&button=" for ::1 at 2019-07-08 22:39:48 +0530
>   Processing by StocksController#search as JS
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "stock"=>"GOOG", "button"=>""}
>     User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>     ↳ /Users/bhanugupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@name/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
>     Rendered users/_result.html.erb (0.9ms)
>     Rendered users/_result.js.erb (3.3ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 15056ms (Views: 5.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Where exactly could this be coming from?

I created a new rails 5.x app yesterday, and I am not sure where this file is being referenced from.

I don't even have a layout for this controller either.

rake routes:

```
api_boards                GET  /api/boards(.:format)                                                                    api/boards#index
api_board                 GET  /api/boards/:id(.:format)                                                                api/boards#show
rails_service_blob        GET  /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET  /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
rails_disk_service        GET  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
rails_direct_uploads      POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Service worker registrations persist across browser restarts, and it's unfortunately common to have an older registration retain control of a common localhost:port combination that's then reused for a different project.

You can unregister the current service worker controlling a page by running

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(r => r.unregister())
```

in the JavaScript console of Chrome's DevTools.

You can see a list of all service worker registrations and unregister them manually in the [Applications panel of Chrome's DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage?hl=en), after clicking on the "Show all" button if needed.

[reference](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache/issues/188#issuecomment-248636350)

Comment: I was searching for one hour. Your response is the first one that works & makes sense. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I get this with every Rail 6.0.0 app I create. Not worked it out yet either.

Answer (score 1):

simple (but dumb) solution is to add the redirect to 404 page into the `routes.rb`

```
get "/sw.js", to: redirect('/404.html')
```